# Missing menu item when creating an app bundle on mac using cx-freeze

Tags: python, macos, pyside, cx-freeze

I have installed python on osx 10.9 via homebrew and cx-freeze 4.3.3 via pip. Creating a binary distribution of a simple PySide program using `python setup.py build` works fine. When using the option `python setup.py bdist_mac` or `python setup.py bdist_dmg` the .app or .dmg file is created ok but the following problem occurs:

The three icons on the top left of the main window are greyed out as is the name of the program. In addition, the *about* entry in the application menu is no longer present. What could be the problem? This was working fine in the binary build.

Comment: Can you give a minimal example of your programm that does show this behavior? Or did you solve the problem in the meantime?